# Create an ID (row number) column

Tags: r, dataframe, r-faq

I need to create a column with unique ID, basically add the row number as an own column.  My current data frame looks like this:

```
   V1  V2
1  23  45
2  45  45
3  56  67
```

How to make it look like this:

```
V1  V2  V3
1  23  45
2  45  45
3  56  67
```

?

Many thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could use `cbind`:

```
d <- data.frame(V1=c(23, 45, 56), V2=c(45, 45, 67))

## enter id here, you could also use 1:nrow(d) instead of rownames
id <- rownames(d)
d <- cbind(id=id, d)

## set colnames to OP's wishes
colnames(d) <- paste0("V", 1:ncol(d))
```

**EDIT:** Here a comparison of @dacko suggestions. `d$id <- seq_len(nrow(d)` is slightly faster, but the order of the columns is different (`id` is the last column; reorder them seems to be slower than using `cbind`):

```
library("microbenchmark")

set.seed(1)
d <- data.frame(V1=rnorm(1e6), V2=rnorm(1e6))

cbindSeqLen <- function(x) {
  return(cbind(id=seq_len(nrow(x)), x))
}

dickoa <- function(x) {
  x$id <- seq_len(nrow(x))
  return(x)
}

dickoaReorder <- function(x) {
  x$id <- seq_len(nrow(x))
  nc <- ncol(x)
  x <- x[, c(nc, 1:(nc-1))]
  return(x)
}

microbenchmark(cbindSeqLen(d), dickoa(d), dickoaReorder(d), times=100)

# Unit: milliseconds
#             expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
#   cbindSeqLen(d) 23.00683 38.54196 40.24093 42.60020 47.73816   100
#        dickoa(d) 10.70718 36.12495 37.58526 40.22163 72.92796   100
# dickoaReorder(d) 19.25399 68.46162 72.45006 76.51468 88.99620   100
```

Comment: Why not  `d$id <- seq_len(nrow(d))` and then `colnames(d) <- paste0("V", 1:ncol(d))`

Comment: @dickoa: I just have not thought of it. Please see my edit. Your solution is a bit faster but doesn't preserve the order of the columns (but this isn't important in most cases).

Answer (score 72):

Two [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse) alternatives (using sgibb's example data):

```
tibble::rowid_to_column(d, "ID")
```

which gives:

> ```
>   ID V1 V2
> 1  1 23 45
> 2  2 45 45
> 3  3 56 67
> ```

Or:

```
dplyr::mutate(d, ID = row_number())
```

which gives:

> ```
>   V1 V2 ID
> 1 23 45  1
> 2 45 45  2
> 3 56 67  3
> ```

As you can see, the `rowid_to_column`-function adds the new column in front of the other ones while the `mutate`&`row_number()`-combo adds the new column after the others.

---

And another base R alternative:

```
d$ID <- seq_along(d[,1])
```

Comment: Curiously, the `mutate` and `seq_along` solutions do not work for `data.table`.

Comment: @JamesHirschorn Besides the method as shown by @altabq (which is the preferred one for [tag:data.table]), you could do `seq_along(d[[1]])` when `d` is a `data.table`.

Answer (score 33):

Many presented their ideas, but I think **this** is the sortest and simplest code for this task:

```
data$ID <- 1:nrow(data)
```

One line. The one and only.

Comment: True, but if your data has 0 rows, then I guess you have no data at all. Therefore, why would you need to create an ID for it?

Comment: In my case, it was inside a function call where the `dataframe` is passed as an argument and is not known in advance. Could have 10 rows one time, 0 the next.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Used     arrange()    first, and then applied     1:nrow()     creating a new variable of sequential IDs. Thank you for this simple solution.

Comment: `data <- cbind(data, 1:nrow(data))` and then followed by `names(data)[names(data)=="1:nrow(data)"] <- "ID"` would be the [Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/R_Programming) way of doing it.

Answer (score 25):

You could also do this using `dplyr`:

```
DF <- mutate(DF, id = rownames(DF))
```

Comment: There is a **big** assumption that rownames are numeric `1:n`.

Answer (score 11):

#### data.table solution

Easier syntax and much faster

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(V1=c(23, 45, 56), V2=c(45, 45, 67))

setnames(dt, c("V2", "V3")) # changing column names
dt[, V1 := .I] # Adding ID column
```

Answer (score 7):

Hope this will help. Shortest and best way to create ID column is:

```
dataframe$ID <- seq.int(nrow(dataframe))
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're starting without named rows in your df, the tidy way is:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  select(id, everything())
```

Comment: How is this different compared to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50909550/2204410)?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution that keeps the dplyr piping format and places id in the first column, which may be preferred.

```
d %>% 
  mutate(id = rownames(.)) %>% 
  select(id, everything())
```

Comment: Suggestion: `relocate(id)` instead of the select statement is more consicse.

Comment: How is this different compared to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26537145/2204410)?

Comment: There is now a `.before` in mutate to control where your new column appears (and not default to far right). So you can do within the mutate:

`d %>%   mutate(id = rownames(.),  .before=everything()) `

or if you don't like the rownames use `id = row_number()` as per Andrew McCartney's solution.

Answer (score 0):

The function `rownames_to_column()` moves rownames into a column; found in the `tidyverse` package ([docs](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/rownames.html)).

```r
rownames_to_column(DF, "my_column_name")
```

Use `column_to_rownames()` for the reverse operation.

Answer (score 0):

If your database is not too large this will work

```
# Load sample data
Dt1 <- tibble(V1=c(23,45,56),V2=c(45,45,67))
# Create Separate Tibble with row numbers
Dt2 <- tibble(id=seq(1:nrow(Dt1)))
# Join together
Dt3 <- cbind(Dt2,Dt1)
```