# Assigning Unique Values

Tags: r, uniqueidentifier

I have a data frame (02outcomes$transfusion_date) in which I have a series of dates that look like this:

```r
2020-03-28 18:01:00
2020-03-28 22:16:00
2020-04-01 19:30:00
2020-04-01 23:56:00
```

I would like to assign unique IDs to each like this:

```r
1   2020-03-28 18:01:00
2   2020-03-28 22:16:00
3   2020-04-01 19:30:00
4   2020-04-01 23:56:00
```

The values need to be in chronological order, ascending.

On a side note, when I view my data using the dput function it looks like this, is that problematic?:

```r
1588635000, 1588706160, 1588714320, 1588721640, 1588881900
```

I found a thread that seems to be similar but cannot seem to make these solutions work:
[Create an ID (row number) column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16384933/create-an-id-row-number-column)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Timestamps in R are `numeric` underneath, with some attributes that make it display as a timestamp. This seems natural to me, since hours, seconds, milliseconds ... are just floating point seconds. So yes, it will show the floating-point numbers. BTW: it would be best to give us unambiguous data such as the output from `dput` (which is completely unambiguous).

Comment: Your sample data is ... completely uninteresting in the sense that a legitimate answer could be `seq_len(nrow(\`02outcomes\`))` (btw, that name is hard to work with in many cases). If you care about duplicate timestamps having the same id, then please update your sample as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

arrange the data by `transfusion_date` and then you can create a unique index for each row.

In base R, you can do :

```
outcomes <- outcomes[order(outcomes$transfusion_date), ]
outcomes$ID <- seq_len(nrow(outcomes))
```

Or using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
outcomes %>% arrange(transfusion_date) %>% mutate(Id = row_number())
```

Answer (score 3):

I feel like you could use `order`:

```
outcomes$id = order(outcomes$transfusion_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the data to 'data.table' (`setDT`), `order` the 'transfusion_date' and assign 'Id' on the sequence of rows

```
library(data.table)
setDT(outcomes)[order(transfusion_date), Id := seq_len(.N)][]
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the input. I used this one

```
outcomes <- outcomes[order(outcomes$transfusion_date), ]
```

outcomes$ID <- seq_len(nrow(outcomes))

Comment: Very good point (obviously), however I very much doubt she s trying to claim any creative credit. Most likely the OP s just (very) unfamiliar with how the forum works.

Comment: thanks, you're correct devsal i didn't realize how it works. is there a way to undo it and accept the answer?

Answer (score -2):

You can use dplyr

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)


testing <- data.frame(dates = c(ymd_hms("2020-03-28 18:01:00"),
                                ymd_hms("2020-03-28 22:16:00"),
                                ymd_hms("2020-04-01 19:30:00"),
                                ymd_hms("2020-04-01 23:56:00")))

testing %>% 
  arrange(dates) %>% 
  mutate(ids = row_number())
```

Comment: Please consider being more specific than `tidyverse`. There are some (many?) who do not have the entire meta-package installed, though they might have the necessary components installed. Similarly, if I were to come across this answer, it would be useful to know specifically which packages were required (so that the dependency-bloom is controlled). In this case, I think it's just `dplyr`. Just like it is best for questions to be the minimum required (which includes not loading unnecessary packages), it is nice when answers are equally minimal. Just a thought/recommendation. Thanks!

Comment: I don't agree, one of the nice things about loading the tidyverse is that it literally opens up a universe of packages and therefore answers to entire new questions, if they are new enough to be asking about very simple things, they are new enough not to care about package bloat