# creating unique ID column in a large dataset

Tags: r, package, dataset, large-data, uniqueidentifier

How to create a column for unique IDs replacing the old unique IDs in a large dataset, as large as around 26000 observations?

I have a dataset with 26000 observations and need to create a unique ID for each year in the dataset. For example, for 2000 I have about 2000 IDs for individuals and the new dataset will consist of a new number for each individual in 2000 for example 20001. Similarly, for every year from 2000 to 2018, I need to create unique IDs with a year number and the already existing ID number and the total number of observations in the dataset is 26668. How to do it in R?

I tried this

New2 <- df1 %>%
mutate(NewID = 20000 + (year - min(year)) * 10000 + id)

but this is not generating a unique ID for 2002, 2004 etc. For example for year 2000 the already existing ID for an individual is 1. The new column should look like 20001. For 2002 it should look like 20021. There are about 2000-4000 observations for each year and the years range from 2000-2018. How to resolve this in R?

Comment: can't you use `rowid_to_column(df)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create an ID (row number) column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16384933/create-an-id-row-number-column)

Comment: It would probably help if you shared a few sample observations (10 or so) then what you would want the output to looks like. Right now this seems like a very simple task and I’m unclear of the logic. Good luck!

Comment: @jpsmith I have edited the question and added the chunks of code I tried and the image of the outcome. The link of the image is embedded in the question itself.

Comment: @Mark I have edited the question and added the image of the outcome. Could you please elaborate on your suggestion?

Comment: Can you create an example which conclusively shows what you are looking for? I don't know if I follow your example right now

Comment: i.e. what is wrong with your code? What is wrong with the duplicate answer?

Comment: Your edit didn’t help much, multiple folks here have asked for reproducible example data and output and the edit contains neither. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/12109788) for some tips. Also images of data are highly discouraged for these reasons: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @jpsmith I apologize, I was not online, and on the contrary, I am frustrated for not being able to resolve the problem. Allow me some time to post the example code. Also, I am new to Stack Overflow and, therefore, my postings could be messy, just bear with me and I will learn to post better. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the `newIDs` you have just created.

```
> library(dplyr)
> YourData %>%
+   mutate(NewID = newIDs)
  OldID Value  NewID
1     1     1 NewID1
2     2     2 NewID2
3     3     3 NewID3
4     4     4 NewID4
```

Or do it in one step.

```
> YourData %>%
+   mutate(NewID = paste0("NewID", seq_len(nrow(.))))
  OldID Value  NewID
1     1     1 NewID1
2     2     2 NewID2
3     3     3 NewID3
4     4     4 NewID4
```

### Edit

This actually works for any number of observations.

```
> dat %>%
  +   mutate(NewID = paste0("NewID", seq_len(nrow(.))))
OldID Value    NewID
1       1     1   NewID1
2       2     2   NewID2
3       3     3   NewID3
...
10     10    10  NewID10
11     11    11  NewID11
...
100   100   100 NewID100
101   101   101 NewID101
...
```

If you don't like different lengths of the IDs, you can try `sprintf` where `%05d` defines number of digits of the number part.

```
> dat %>%
  +   mutate(NewID = sprintf("NewID%05d", seq_len(nrow(.))))
OldID Value      NewID
1       1     1 NewID00001
2       2     2 NewID00002
3       3     3 NewID00003
```

To avoid hard coding the `5`, you could do this hack.

```
> dat %>%
  +   mutate(NewID = sprintf(sprintf('NewID%%0%sd', nchar(nrow(dat))), seq_len(nrow(.))))
OldID Value      NewID
1       1     1 NewID00001
2       2     2 NewID00002
3       3     3 NewID00003
```

---

*Data:*

```
> YourData <- data.frame(OldID = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), Value = c(1, 2, 3, 4))
> newIDs <- paste0("NewID", seq_len(nrow(YourData)))

> n <- 26000
> dat <- data.frame(OldID = as.character(seq_len(n)), Value = seq_len(n))
```

Comment: creating vectors for 26000 observations is the issue I am facing.

Comment: @ShaD. Shouldn't be a problem, please see edit.

Comment: Hi! I have updated the question. I guess it lacked clarity and I have shared my code.

Comment: @ShaD. I see, can you please make appropriate example data as you did before? And please use the Stack Overflow utilities to format your code as code, it's hard to read.